# Which are available drivers updates using command line?

Tags: java, windows, swing, netbeans, command-line

The program is being designed for `Windows 10` and I have been stuck on this for a while now. Using `Java runtime` execution I'd like to search for any available driver updates. What are my options?

So far I've discovered the `devcon` utility but I haven't found a way to utilize that to search for available updates.

The end result I need to achieve is a program that will list out all of a user's PC drivers, scan thru them to find updateable ones, and then guide the user through downloading them. Once downloaded the user clicks to install. `DevCon` provides the functionality to do all of this except for finding updateable ones.